# Is there an API for the Quick Find functionality in the Setup Menu?

Tags: api, documentation

I've been looking through the API docs, and see APIs for most things except Quick Find. Is there any documented or undocumented API for it?

Comment: Are you referring to the Quick Find in the Setup menu?

Comment: @JayantDas I am. Is [Selenium](https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/salesforce-with-selenium/) the only option?

Comment: There's no API available for Quick Find. That's more of a manual step that you can perform while being on Setup menu. I am not sure about your use case, but I wouldn't think you will even want to perform any validation around Quick Find with Selenium. Can you elaborate, what is your use case here?

Comment: @JayantDas My use case is to migrate the [create sample account](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/debugger_puzzle_create_accounts.htm) functionality from Force.com IDE to a [cli plugin](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/create-your-first-salesforce-cli-plugin.html).

Comment: I don't have much experience on the plugin development, but I don't think you need Quick Find for this. You would just need to call the standard REST API to create Account records. You may like to explore in that direction.

Comment: @JayantDas Thanks. The issue there is not the REST API, but working with [non-scratch orgs](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/using-salesforcedx-sfdx-with-non-scratch-orgs/) is not fully automated. I was hoping to automate account creation, and I know Selenium, but I was hoping to do it via an API.

Comment: If you're looking at the step in that exercise where FLS is updated, that's something you could be doing by changing the profile metadata, or better still pushing up a Permission Set and assigning it to yourself. You don't need UI scripting to update FLS.